# How to call js Function from setInterval()

Tags: javascript, jquery, qtip

AIM: I would like to set the below function to call every 5 seconds. Using qtip.

The variable ALARM_POPUP changes every minute via a shellscript which replaces the contents on the variable.

CODE:

```
    function popupTXT()

         {

              var ALARM_POPUP="Alarm Warning warning ";

              $('#telecom_1').qtip({content:ALARM_POPUP,style: {name: 'dark', tip: 'topLeft'} });

        };
```

I am using the below to call on a timer.

```
    setInterval("popupTXT()",5000);
```

OUTCOME: This will only work when I refresh the browser. Any suggestions would be appreciated

Comment: Even if you call the function every 5 seconds how are you going to update the content of `ALARM_POPUP`? It seems to be generated on the server, but once it is downloaded to browser it won't change unless you're doing some ajax requests

Comment: @user628405 the content of ALARM_POPUP is change via a shell script which uses sed s to substitute current text with new text. It is always updated, its just that the jquery isn't picking it up without refreshing the window and I can't do that because of other parts of the page.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> The variable `ALARM_POPUP` changes every minute via a shellscript which replaces the contents on the variable.

That means that in order to see that change on the page, you have to call the server to get an updated value. You're not doing that.

You could do that via [`ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax). Create a server-side page that outputs the new value for `ALARM_POPUP` as raw text (using `Content-Type: text/plain`) or as JSON (using `Content-Type: application/json`), and trigger an `ajax` call to get the contents of that page, then update the `qtip` with it. You wouldn't want `setInterval` for that because with the indeterminate length of time the `ajax` call would take, things would very quickly become chaotic. Instead, just initiate a `setTimeout` upon completion of the previous cycle.

Assuming you create an `updatealarm.xyz` page (PHP, JSP, ASP.Net, whatever) that outputs the current `ALARM_POPUP` value as plain text, that would look *something* like this:

```
(function()
{
    var ALARM_POPUP="Alarm Warning warning ";

    function updateQtip(popupText)
    {
        $('#telecom_1').qtip({content:popupText,style: {name: 'dark', tip: 'topLeft'} });
        setTimeout(nextUpdate, 5000);
    }

    function nextUpdate()
    {
        $.ajax({
            url: "updatealarm.xyz",
            success: function(data)
            {
                ALARM_POPUP = data; // Although you don't actually need to update it
                updateQtip(data);
            },
            error: function()
            {
                // Do error handling
            }
        });
    }

    updateQtip();

})();
```

About your original `setInterval` call: It's best not to pass strings into `setInterval` or `setTimeout`; that's basically doing an `eval`, and it's neither necessary nor a good idea. Instead, pass in a function reference (e.g., the function's name, without `()` calling it), as above.

---

Re your comment below:

> I am having problems with this and I was wondering if you provide an example of what the php file would look like

I've only done a little PHP, but I believe it would look like this:

```
<?php
    header('Content-Type: text/plain');
    echo 'This is the message that will end up in \'data\' in the ajax success handler.';
?>
```

Or if you prefer to use a variable to make it easier for your `sed` script:

```
<?php
    header('Content-Type: text/plain');
    $alarm_popup = 'This is the message that will end up in \'data\' in the ajax success handler.';
    echo $alarm_popup;
?>
```

Comment: @TJCrowder Thanks for your detailed response. the variable is actively being changed on the html page via a sed command on the shell script. But the function still isn't picking up the var change. If I check the HTML, the code has changed to the new alarm content.

Comment: @Rhys: The key point is **client vs. server** copies of the page. When the browser requests the page, the server sends it a *copy* of the page as it exists then. Your `sed` script changes the page ***on the server***, not on the client. It doesn't (and can't) change the client display of the page That's why you have to ask the server for updates. Obviously you don't want to ask the server for the whole page again, so do a separate page. Have the `sed` script *also* update `updatedalarm.xyz` and the above should sort things out, because the client-code requests the updated file from the server.

Comment: @TJCrowder Thats makes sense, thanks for that. I am also running jquery draggable() on this page. Won't that cause problems?

Comment: @tjcrowder Sorry to be a pain, but I am having problems with this and I was wondering if you provide an example of what the php file would look like. Thanks

Comment: @TJCrowder Legend, working great now. You missing a closing brace in your code example. I have updated it. Thanks again.

Comment: @Rhys: Glad that helped. I've fixed the missing `)` on the `qtip` call -- it came from the code in your question, so I fixed it there too.

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
setInterval(popupTXT,5000);
```

**[Just a sample](http://jsfiddle.net/QStkd/261/)**

Read more about **[.setInterval()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.setInterval)**

Comment: Re-reading the question, while you're quite right that it's better to use `setInterval` with a function reference than a string, I don't think that's the OP's problem.